# Editing ActionBar in Eclipse - Android

Tags: android

I am working on a new Android application with a navigation with the fixed tabs and scroll-able default option Eclipse gives you.

But when looking on my `.xml` files for the `mainActivity` and the dummy file that are generated automatically, I can't find out where to edit the titles and whatnot for each individual tab section.

Do you know what I need to do?

Comment: Please look at this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html This is pretty basic stuff that can be searched for before putting it on SO

Comment: @RSenApps what I am trying to figure out is there a place I can edit this stuff or do I just have to enter code and go from there?

Comment: you mean you want to edit the title of buttons in ActionBar; go to res/menu/main.xml or if exist other files check them. I hope i got it true

Comment: Yes but the only thing is them is one item and it says to never show: `android:showAsAction="never"` - that is the weird thing, the way it populates the tabs is with this: `getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);` so this is what is really confusing me because the value of that does not equal 1 its a bunch of random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default value of tabs by changing res/values/string.xml>title_section(x). Note: using resource string files should be something you get very familiar with as you should try your best to separate any "magic strings" from your code. Basically all strings should go in a resource file and be referenced through getString.

Comment: Ho would I go about updating the styles of the tabs and everything?

Comment: Use this: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ Please accept my answer if it helped you :)